# Best way to execute simple async task in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency

I want to asynchronously invoke a function which does something separately from main thread. I'm new in Java concurrency, so i ask what is the best way to perform action like this:

```
for(File myFile : files){
    MyFileService.resize(myfile)  <--- this should be async
}
```

The while loop goes on while function `MyFileService.resize` works in background with each of my files in collection.

I heard that CompletionStage from Java8 could be good way to do it.
What is the best way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) in *Java8*, example:

```
for(File myFile : files){
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> MyFileService.resize(myfile))
}
```

For `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` default will use [ForkJoinPool common pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), the default thread size is: `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1`, also you can modify this by:

1. `System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", size)`
2. `Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=size`

also you can use `supplyAsync` method with your own [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), like:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> MyFileService.resize(myfile), executorService)
```

Answer (score 2):

The "most simple" straight forward solution is to create a "bare metal" Thread on the fly and have it call that method. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for details.

Of course, programming is always about adding levels of abstractions; and in that sense, you can look into using an ExecutorService. And as you are mentioning java8, this [here](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/) would be a good starting point (that also shows how to use ordinary Threads in a more java8 style).

Answer (score 1):

Most simple would be (with Java 8):

```
for(File myFile : files){
  new Thread( () -> MyFileService.resize(myfile)).start();
}
```